# how to update Final AMOUNT Intially having NULL in all rows

Tags: oracle

```
**seq**   **amt1**          **amt2**     **int_amt**  **final_amt**
   1        500               NuLL          2000         2500
   2        Null              NULL          NULL         2500   
   3        NULL              NULL          NULL         2500
   4        200               NULL          NULL         2700
```

Update final_amt by applying  final_amt=int_amt+amt1-amt2 for first row
and then final_amt=final_amt+amt1-amt2 for all rows if amt1 and amt2 having NULL for a row then final_amt should contain previous value of final_amt IN ORACLE;

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery.  This appears to do what you want, given that `int_amt` is `NULL` after the first row:

```
update t
    set final_amt = (select coalesce(sum(amt1), 0) - coalesce(sum(amt2), 0) + coalesce(sum(int_amt), 0)
                         from t t2
                         where t2.seq <= t.seq
                        );
```

If you wanted to ignore `int_amt` after the first row, then use `case`:

```
update t
    set final_amt = (select (coalesce(sum(amt1), 0) - coalesce(sum(amt2), 0) +
                             (case when seq > 1 then 0 else coalesce(sum(int_amt), 0) end)
                            )
                         from t t2
                         where t2.seq <= t.seq
                        );
```